# hive left join not working

Tags: sql, join, hive

my user table contains following data as columns

```
region,cust no,mobileno,null,host,null,usage,null,usageduration
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Facebook        NULL    2.9384765625    NULL    1.726
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    HTTP    NULL    1.0146484375    NULL    0.232
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Bing    NULL    8.8642578125    NULL    0.746
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Crashlytics     NULL    19.4599609375   NULL    48.765
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    DNS     NULL    17.4296875      NULL    584.596
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Doubleclick     NULL    6.908203125     NULL    1.362
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Dropbox NULL    37.0380859375   NULL    42.174
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Facebook        NULL    21.1533203125   NULL    29.689
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google  NULL    49.0732421875   NULL    28.456
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google APIs     NULL    213.8642578125  NULL    49.866
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google Ads      NULL    5.7314453125    NULL    0.932
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google Calendar NULL    0.201171875     NULL    0.06
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google Cloud Messaging  NULL    8.5419921875    NULL    143.50799999999998
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Google Play     NULL    228.7880859375  NULL    88.77600000000001
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    HTTP    NULL    0.29296875      NULL    1.16
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    NTP     NULL    0.1484375       NULL    0.122
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    SSL     NULL    96.095703125    NULL    452.88
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    Skype   NULL    93.6953125      NULL    67.649
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    TCP     NULL    93.591796875    NULL    117.32900000000001
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    WhatsApp        NULL    165780.6171875  NULL    1097.055
AP      404070620021081 Prepaid 919848052151    NULL    XMPP    NULL    62.4453125      NULL    350.03700000000003


my top20 table contains host,rank
SSL                     1
TCP                     2
DNS                     3
HTTP                    4
Facebook                5
Google Play             6
Google Cloud Messaging  7
YouTube                 8
UDP                     9
XMPP                    10
Skype                   11
WhatsApp                12
Bittorrent              13
Google                  14
STUN                    15
Google APIs             16
Doubleclick             17
Apple                   18
MDNS                    19
Google Ads              20
```

i need usage,duration for each customer for these top20 sites.if customer didnt used then it should show 0 but 20 rows required for each customer. i done left join but gettin 420 rows with all combination.which is wrong.please suggest to get 20 rows for each customer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find all combinations of cust_no and host using a cross join and then left join user table with it.

```
select t.cust_no,
    t.host,
    coalesce(u.usage, 0) usage,
    coalesce(u.usageduration, 0) usageduration
from (
    select *
    from (
        select distinct cust_no
        from user
        ) u
    cross join top20 t
    ) t
left join user u on t.cust_no = u.cust_no
    and t.host = u.host;
```

Comment: i created a query

Answer (score 0):

Hi i created a query as below

```
SELECT
  imsi,
  msisdn,Subscription_plan,
  cust_nationality,
  application_name,
  rank,is_app,
  total_data_volume_host,
  SUM(total_data_volume_app) AS total_data_volume_app,
  event_duration_host,
  SUM(event_duration_app) AS event_duration_app
FROM (SELECT
  ps_data.cust_nationality,
  ps_data.imsi,ps_data.Subscription_plan,
  ps_data.msisdn,
  ps_data.host,
  top20.host_app AS application_name,
  top20.rank,
  top20.is_app,
  ps_data.total_data_volume_host,
  ps_data.total_data_volume_app,
  ps_data.event_duration_host,
  ps_data.event_duration_app
FROM (SELECT
  circle,
  host_app,
  rank,
  is_app
FROM ps_top20_host_app_1_month
WHERE is_app = '1') top20
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  cust_nationality,
  imsi,Subscription_plan,
  msisdn,
  NULL AS host,
  application_name,
  NULL AS total_data_volume_host,
  SUM(COALESCE(total_data_volume,0)) / 1024 AS total_data_volume_app,
  NULL AS event_duration_host,
  SUM(COALESCE(data_transfer_time_dl, 0)/1000 + COALESCE(data_transfer_time_ul, 0)/1000) AS event_duration_app
FROM ps_data_up_segg_1_day
WHERE content_provider='1' and cust_nationality is not null and UPPER(cust_nationality) not in ('UNKNOWN','NULL IN SOURCE') and 
msisdn is not null and UPPER(msisdn) not in ('UNKNOWN','NULL IN SOURCE') AND dt >= '1487615400000'AND dt < '1487701800000' AND imsi='404070620021081'
GROUP BY cust_nationality,
         imsi,
         msisdn,Subscription_plan,
         host,
         application_name) ps_data
  ON (
  top20.circle = ps_data.cust_nationality) where ( top20.host_app is not null and top20.host_app=ps_data.application_name ) )t2
GROUP BY imsi,
         msisdn,Subscription_plan,
         cust_nationality,
         host,
         application_name,
         rank,is_app,
         total_data_volume_host,
         event_duration_host
```

but am getting only 14 rows which are common not all 20
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      DNS     3       1       NULL    17.4296875      NULL    584.596
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Doubleclick     17      1       NULL    6.908203125     NULL    1.362
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Facebook        5       1       NULL    24.091796875    NULL    31.415
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Google  14      1       NULL    49.0732421875   NULL    28.456
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Google APIs     16      1       NULL    213.8642578125  NULL    49.866
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Google Ads      20      1       NULL    5.7314453125    NULL    0.932
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Google Cloud Messaging  7       1       NULL    8.5419921875    NULL    143.50799999999998
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Google Play     6       1       NULL    228.7880859375  NULL    88.77600000000001
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      HTTP    4       1       NULL    1.3076171875    NULL    1.392
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      SSL     1       1       NULL    96.095703125    NULL    452.88
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      Skype   11      1       NULL    93.6953125      NULL    67.649
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      TCP     2       1       NULL    93.591796875    NULL    117.32900000000001
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      WhatsApp        12      1       NULL    165780.6171875  NULL    1097.055
404070620021081 919848052151    Prepaid AP      XMPP    10      1       NULL    62.4453125      NULL    350.03700000000003
but its wrong for thise user i need 20 records where unused hosts with 0 usage